# Can't find the IP address of my access point in my network

Tags: networking, router, wireless-access-point

HJi, here is my configuration:

I've a fritz router (the root ), and use a powerline to connect it to another room. To the second power point I've connected a Dlink g624t to create a wifi network in the new room. Everything works fine but I can't find the ip of the dlink to change the settings (I wanna create a password for the the wifi).

I've red other questions similar to this here and find this program ( Angry IP scanner ). I've tried but i can't find anything. It seems that the node (the dlink) doesn't exits! But it's connected and working!

Comment: Look into the devices documentation. And read the [help].

Comment: Connect you pc directly to the fitz router and try again.

Comment: You must have connected to the D-link configuration screen to set it up as a bridge or access point (you haven't said which you're using): use the same method of connection to configure the wireless settings. If all else fails do a factory reset and configure wireless before changing operating mode.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the IPs of all other devices on your network and are connected through the Dlink to get on the network you can use:

```
arp -a
```

This should give you a list of devices and IP addresses associated with them.
You will need to run this command from a command prompt in windows or from the terminal in OSx/Linux

Answer (score 1):

Or you can simply scan your whole network to figure out what adresses are responding:

`nmap -sP <your network>`

Where you network is something like `192.168.1.0/24` or `192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0̀

Comment: I've just checked the examples on nmap's website, it loos like it's possible to use another syntax to check IP ranges: 
`nmap -sP 192.168.1-3.0-255` -> will scan IPs from 192.168.1.0 to 192.168.1.255, then 192.168.2.0 to 192.168.2.255, and so on.. @binarym do you confirm that this syntax gives the same result as yours? Cheers

Comment: I do confirm :-)

Answer (score 0):

The default IP for that device is 192.168.1.1 with username of admin and password of admin.

However if your IP range is different (I'm guessing the fritz router is handing out IP's DHCP) then you will need to be in the same range as the Dlink device 192.168.1.x

The easiest way to do this is to plug the ethernet cable directly to the device and give your laptop/PC a static IP address from the IP configuration in network connections. The details you can use are 192.168.1.5 subnet 255.255.255.0 and set the gateway to the dlink IP 192.168.1.1 DNS can be left blank.

Now try to browse to the IP 192.168.1.1 from a web browser and see if the admin page comes up. If not then the default IP has been changed and you might have to factory reset the device to get it back to this IP and be able to configure the device to your requirements.